# Querying for exact match of objects with many to many relationship in Django

Tags: django, many-to-many

I want to write a query that matches on several objects that have manytomany relationships.

To be more clear:

I have 2 models that have many to many relationship with each other.

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
        dish = models.IntField()
        ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient)

class Ingredient(models.Model):
        matching_ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Recipe)
        plate = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

my code:

```
firstfruit = Fruit(dish_id=1234, name='apple')
secondfruit = Fruit(dish_id=1234, name='orange')
salad = Ingredient()
salad.matching_ingredients.add(firstfruit, secondfruit)
matching_ingredients_from_dish = Recipe.objects.all()
```

I tried this but this will return true if anything matches:

```
Recipe.objects.get(matching_ingredients=matching_ingredients_from_dish)
```

I want to see if every matching_ingredients matches with every matching_ingredients_from_dish like an exact match.

Comment: Can you add in the model code for `Fruit`? I'm guessing that's a model.  Your many to many setup looks a bit weird to me. Are you sure you really want relationships in both directions like that rather than one relationship with a related_name?

Comment: Yeah i cant see why you would want to define the relationship on both sides when django provides backwards compatabilty to access the relationship for either side IE: recipe.ingredients.all() or backwards via ingrediants.recipe_set.all() or if you defined a related_name as @Duncan Parkes mentioned you could go backwards through the related name